# Suspicious estimates of ARMA-GARCH parameters in `rugarch` in `R`

Tags: r

I am facing a problem in ARMA-GARCH modelling in `R`. The model is specified by `ugarchspec` and fitted by `ugarchfit` in `rugarch` package. The solver produces an ARMA part with AR and MA coefficients essentially cancelling each other. For example, I get ARMA(2,2) with 


`AR1 = 1.72, AR2 = -1.71, MA1 = -1.8341, MA2 = 1.8346`.


I suppose that this set of parameters is a local maximum of the surface of model likelihood, and the optimizer used in `ugarchfit` unfortunately reach it instead of reaching the global maximum. 


Is there a way to avoid such situations? Perhaps it is possible to constrain parameters using `ugarchfit` so that such local maxima would be excluded a priori? For example, set some inequality constraints on parameters a priori, e.g. 


`| AR1 - AR2 | > 0.01`


or, perhaps better, to do the same for the characteristic roots of AR and MA parts (so that they are not too close), or similar. Any ideas and help will be appreciated!